# How to train multiple inputs for Perceptron in C#?

Tags: c#, machine-learning

I recently just coded a perceptron that takes in an OR gate as it's value. However, currently my code can only train 1 point whereas I want it to train 4 point of the OR gate. Here's my attached code, I am still learning how to program so please excuse me for some of my errors.

```c
using System;
using ActivationFunction;
namespace Perceptron
{
    class Point
    {


        private double input1; //creates private field
        public double Input1 { get => input1; set => input1 = value; } //creates public property (important for encapsulation of data)
        private double input2;
        public double Input2 { get => input2; set => input2 = value; }
        private double desiredOutput;
        public double DesiredOutput { get => desiredOutput; set => desiredOutput = value; }

        public Point() /*Creates an empty constructor so that the object of the
                       class can be instantiated to refer variables*/
        {

        }

        public Point(int input1, int input2, int desiredOutput) //Takes in the inputs for the perceptron
        {

            this.input1 = input1;
            this.input2 = input2;
            this.desiredOutput = desiredOutput;

            Console.WriteLine("INPUT 1 => " + Input1);
            Console.WriteLine("INPUT 2 => " + Input2);
            Console.WriteLine("DESIRED OUTPUT => " + desiredOutput);
        }
    }

    class NeuralNetwork
    {
        readonly Point point = new Point(); //used for referring variables from point to class

        private double[] weights = new double[3];

        private double output; 

        private const double bias = 1; //creates constant bias

        private double error; 

        private const double learningRate = 0.25; //constant learningRate 

        public NeuralNetwork(Point point) //Might be unnecessary...
        {
            this.point = point;
        }

        public void RandomiseWeightsAndBias()
        {
            Random rand = new Random();

            for (int i = 0; i < weights.Length; i++) //loops through the weights
            {
                weights[i] = rand.NextDouble();

                weights[i] -= 0.5; // expected range now -0.5 to +0.5
                weights[i] *= 2; //expected range now -1 to 1

                Console.WriteLine("STARTING SYNAPTIC WEIGHTS => " + weights[i]);

            }

            Console.WriteLine("BIAS IS => " + bias);
        }

        public double DotProductBias() //Sums up the inputs and weights together
        {

            return point.Input1 * weights[0] + point.Input2 * weights[1] + bias * weights[2];
        }

        public double ActivationFunction() //Applies activation function
        {
            DotProductBias();
            output = ActivationFunctions.StepActivation(DotProductBias()); //The Activation Function is in part of another class, there is a built in static function that takes in a static double as input
            return output;
        }


        public void CalculateError() //Calculate Error
        {
            error = point.DesiredOutput - output;
            Console.WriteLine("ERROR IS => " + error);
        }

        public void AdjustWeights() //Perform gradient descent
        {

            weights[0] += learningRate * weights[0] + error * point.Input1; //I know I can use for loops to make it more concise and clean but it works for now
            weights[1] += learningRate * weights[1] + error * point.Input2;
            weights[2] += learningRate * weights[2] + error * bias;

            for (int i = 0; i < weights.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ADJUSTED WEIGHTS ARE => " + weights[i]);
            }


        }

        public void Train(int epochs) //Training or "backpropagating the weights"
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < epochs; i++)
            {
                AdjustWeights();
            }
        }

    }

    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var point = new Point(0, 1, 1);

            /*
            var point2 = new Point(0, 1, 0);
            var point3 = new Point(1, 0, 0);
            var point4 = new Point(1, 1, 1);
            */

            var neuralNetwork = new NeuralNetwork(point);

            neuralNetwork.RandomiseWeightsAndBias();
            neuralNetwork.ActivationFunction();
            neuralNetwork.CalculateError();
            neuralNetwork.Train(8);

            Console.WriteLine("THE FINAL OUTPUT IS " + neuralNetwork.ActivationFunction());

        }
    }

}
```

Looking at the code, it's clear that I need to change the values of the constructors in the Point class, perhaps change the inputs to an array or a list? Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, there are several possible troubles here, first it looks that the points you want to train are not OR gate but XOR gate and a single perceptron can't implement XOR. The reason is that the classes in XOR are not linearly separable. You cannot draw a straight line to separate the points (0,0),(1,1) from the points (0,1),(1,0). OR gate would be [0,0,0] [1,0,1] [1,1,1] [0,1,1] , read more about it here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OR_gate.

Second, to me it looks like your weight adjustment is wrong - to adjust weights in perception we use this formula NEW WEIGHT = WEIGHT + ERROR * INPUT * LEARNING RATE, and in your example, you did multiply it by your weight once more.

In such simple example it's convinient to use threshold activation function which is basically - If output < 0 return 0 else return 1.